# tick symbol not appearing in xslt

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have an xslt file where i have used the below code snippet. I have used ✓ for a tick symbol infront of Hello World. The xslt is used to parse and xml response and render to an HTML.

```
<td colspan="2" class="cellwhite font13 fontNormal" align="center">
                                            <span>&#10003;</span> Hello World
                                    </td>
```

But the tick symbol is not appearing in html file.
it is coming as a^?? .

Comment: How do you use XSLT exactly, which XSLT processor do you use, how do you run it (command line, IDE, with code in a host language), how do you look at the HTML file created? Do you use `<xsl:output method="html"/>` to ensure the processor, if in charge of serialization, outputs a `meta` element in the `head` section to indicate the content type and charset?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have generated an HTML file that is correctly encoded in UTF-8, and you are viewing it with some piece of software that doesn't know it is UTF-8, or that can't handle UTF-8. You need to look at how the HTML is being displayed.

Comment: UTF -8 is handled, there are existing contents that is displayed but for the first time i tried htmlcode.

Comment: i tried HTML Entity (Hexadecimal) and HTML Entity (Decimal) for tick but it is not rendering in html

Comment: <xsl:if test="//results/bshdggd/hhjjjsh != '' ">
      
       <table class="primaryHeader" align="center">
        
        <tr>
         <td colspan="2" class="cellwhite font13 fontNormal" align="center">
           <span>&#10003;</span> Hello World
         </td>
         
         <td></td>
        </tr>
       </table>
       
      
      </xsl:if>